# Why is a go application binary different sizes when building using dependencies in a vendor directory vs dependencies in gopath?

Tags: go, glide-golang

I have a main.go file with a glide.yaml file (see below for source code) in a clean gopath (No other repositories)

Running `go get -u ./...` then `go build main.go` generates a binary of size 2377872 bytes.

Cleaning the gopath of any repos that were cloned from `go get`, and running `glide update` then `go build main.go` generates a binary of size 2457328 bytes.

Why are binaries of different sizes, if there was no code changes?
What does `go build` do differently? Why does having a vendor directory (or not having one) affect this size?

Software versions used

```
glide version 0.13.1
go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main () {
    log.WithFields(log.Fields{
        "qqs": "q1",
    }).Info("Why are binaries different?")
}
```

glide.yaml

```
package: github.com/chuyval/qqs/q1
import:
- package: github.com/sirupsen/logrus
  version: 1.0.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go build` by default includes debugging information in the executable, including the path of the source code files.

When you have a `vendor/` directory the path of the source files will be longer than when you the source files lie inside `GOPATH`. As a result, the debugging information will take up more space.

Try comparing the size of the built binary by telling `go build` to exclude the debugging information like this.

```
go build -ldflags=-s ./
```

That reduces the difference in size. See https://golang.org/cmd/link/ for more details about the linker flags.

*(Edit: the source file paths are included when debugging information is not included as well as is evidenced by stack traces from a `panic()`, so this answer is not complete)*

Comment: Using `go build -ldflags=-s ./` gave me the same result. I found that using `-w` flag reduces the sizes to 1552112 with a vendor dir and 1550480 w/o a vendor dir. Still different, but makes sense why they would be with your explanation.

Comment: @chuy perhaps it's because I'm using Go 1.11 that I see the resulting binaries to be the same size with just the `-s` flag. There's more going on of course and maybe if I have a lot more dependencies, the sizes would be different. There's still some source file info required for stack traces on `panic()` so maybe that's where the additional space is used...